# Automatically creating hyperlink to another sheet by text

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how to create a hyperlink from one excel sheet to another, automatically through a script, based on equal text values that both cells in their respective sheets have.

If this can be done without a script, using a formula of some kind (like VLOOKUP) this would be preferable.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Are both sheets in the same workbook? Are you comparing values in the same column on both sheets?

Comment: User the `HYPERLINK` function within a conditional formula, e.g. `IF`. That's the best I can offer based on the detail you provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Hyperlink on same sheet using a value in A1:

**=HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(MATCH(A1, B1:B5, 0), 2), "Link")**

- Hyperlink to a specific different sheet using a value in A1:

**=HYPERLINK("#'My Database'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH($A1, 'My Database'!$A:$A, 0), 1), "Link")**

- Hyperlink to a sheet listed in cell A1

**=HYPERLINK("#'" & A1 & "'!A1", "Link")**

- Hyperlink to a random position in a column that must be found on a random sheet listed in cell C3, matching the value in A1, a 3D INDEX/MATCH/Hyperlink:

**=HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address", INDEX(INDIRECT(C3 & "!A:A"), MATCH(A1, INDIRECT(C3 & "!A:A"), 0))), "Link")**

There's a sample sheet found here where you can see these applied:
***[3D Hyperlink Examples](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/search-functions/3d-hyperlink)***