# hyperlink in visual basic excel

Tags: excel, vba

what i want in the code is that when i click this cell B3 in sheet1 it will direct me to A5 in sheet2 then vice versa, when i click A5 in sheet2 it will bring back me to B3 in sheet1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUngD.jpg

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Sheet2!A5", TextToDisplay:="gg"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Sheet1!B3", TextToDisplay:="gg"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

now my problem is what if the name of the sheet is userdefined? there's a messagebox that says you should input the name of the sheet. so the sub address now changes it is not just "Sheet2" anymore. for instance you put in the msgbox "123", the name of the sheet would now become "Sheet2 123".

Comment: `when i click a button, the cell B3 in shee1t becomes blue or indicating it has hyperlink` - can you explain this better?

Comment: you should iterate through the worksheets collection. if the sheets are always indexed 1 and 2 then go by index in the back end instead of the name

Comment: the name of the worksheet depends on the input defined by the user. can i use '&'? i tried to add it "Sheet2 &" but error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of indexing of worksheets collection.

```
Sub IndexingSheets()
    Sheets(1).Range("B3").Formula = _
     "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name & "!A5"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
    Sheets(2).Range("A5").Formula = _
     "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "!B3"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
End Sub
```

This code assumes your sheet1 and sheet2 are always the first two sheets in the workbook.

---

But if you wanted to ask for the name then you could use this instead:
code checks if the sheet already exists ( so you can refer to it ). If it does then it executes the macro and if it doesn't then it calls the procedure recursively to ask for another name.

```
Dim sheetExist As Boolean

Sub PrefNamedSheets()

    Dim shName$, i&
    shName = InputBox("Whats the second sheet name?")
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If StrComp(CStr(Sheets(i).Name), shName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetExist = True
        End If
    Next i
    If sheetExist Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Formula = _
         "=HYPERLINK(""#" & shName & "!A5"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
        Sheets(shName).Range("A5").Formula = _
         "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "!B3"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
    Else
        Call PrefNamedSheets
    End If
End Sub
```

You may also find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130040/automatically-creating-hyperlink-to-another-sheet-by-text) useful!

Comment: i tried the 1st code you've posted, but when i clicked it, it says reference is not valid. also i forgot to say that there are hidden worksheets. does the hidden worksheet counts in the indexing of sheets?

Comment: oops i'm sorry wrong post. does the hidden worksheet counts in the indexing of sheets?

Comment: @kazSone `This code assumes your sheet1 and sheet2 are always the first two sheets in the workbook.` If you are sure about the structure of your workbook, ie. you know which 2 sheets you need for your references then you use the first code. Just make sure your sheet indexes refer to the correct sheets. Otherwise, you should use the second solution.

Comment: @kazSone try it yourself! hide some sheets then msgbox the count. -- or refer to the MSDN

Comment: just making sure, the hidden sheets are included in indexing. but when i tried it, reference is still not valid. but the location where it should link is now correct.

Comment: @kazSone youre going off topic with all your questions. This is a specific answer to a specific problem. If you have more questions please post a new one.